# How is the `break` keyword implemented in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I looked around in the official documentation but I haven't found a description of how it actually works to terminate a loop.

Comment: So you want someone to point you to the C code in the Ruby interpeter that implements break?  That might be pretty complex or hard to understand, and you don't actually need to understand that to use break.

Comment: @DavidGrayson guess that depends on what the question behind this question really is :)